# Нужно ли обособлять "по крайней мере" запятыми? Оно употребляется здесь в роли вводного сочетания или члена предложения? Нужна ли запятая перед "как"?

Tags: пунктуация, вводные-слова, сравнение

Двор замка был огромным, как поле, или по крайней мере казался таким Даврану.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поскольку в вашем случае этот оборот используется в значении *"во всяком случае"*, то выделяется запятыми. [Правило](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_556).